# Create (and select from) a table dynamically using servicestack ormlite

Tags: c#, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I am using `C#`, and I try to create a table, using `ServiceStack.OrmLite`, corresponding to a class type created in **run-time**, I searched for the topic and I have found the following solution:

- After creating the type in `runtime (employeeType)`, I could do the following:

  ```
  db.CreateTableIfNotExists(employeeType);
  ```

This would create the table Employee corresponding to the (dynamically created type "Employee")

- Then, by using the following:

  ```
  var typedApi = db.CreateTypedApi(employeeType);
  ```

I could get a TypedApi which could be used to insert, delete, update the Employee table created dynamically.

- In fact, my problem is that I cannot make a simple select statement from the table "Employee" because that requires to pass a generic `type T` which I don't have, as follows:

  ```
  db.Select<T>(); // T is supposed to be my "employeeType" created  dynamically.
  ```

Is it possible to make a select from a table corresponding to a run-time created type ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Yes it is possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrmLite APIs and SqlExpression are Typed, but you can execute Custom SQL for your runtime Type, e.g:

```
var modelDef = employeeType.GetModelMetadata();
var tableName = db.GetDialectProvider().GetQuotedTableName(modelDef);
var sql = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}";
```

Which you can then Select using one of the [dynamic result set APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#dynamic-result-sets), e.g:

```
var results = db.Select<List<object>>(sql);
var results = db.Select<Dictionary<string,object>>(sql);
var results = db.Select<dynamic>(sql);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. In fact, I was searching for another solution than using custom SQL! I suppose that this is the only way to do what I want to do. Anyway, that seems to do the job :)